Utilize google cloud monitoring's alerting policies in Postgres Database
I want to setup an alerting policy using google cloud monitoring for a table in Postgres Database. Is there a direct way to setup such policies or I need to involve MQL, cloud functions etc as an intermediator?
I tried log based metrics
